# ggplotly with histogram -- cannot make it work

Tags: r, animation, histogram, ggplotly

I am trying to animate a histogram with an overlaid density function via `ggplotly`, using a code that looks like

```
ggplot() +
   geom_point(data_1 = aes(..some aesthetic.., frame = step)) +
   geom_hist(data_2 = aes(..some other aesthetic.., frame = step))
```

This code does not work, but it seems to me that in general histograms do not work with `ggplotly`. I am wondering if any of you could help.

**Data**

Here is an example; `frame` is the variable to define the animation index

```
# Some data (points) for the first aes
df_1 = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, frame = 1:10)

# Other data (for each frame multiple values from 3 groups)
df_2 = lapply(1:10, function(w)
         data.frame(
            val = runif(10, min = w, max = w + 1),  # Value
            code = sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE), # Color for fill
            frame = w)
         )
df_2 = Reduce(rbind, df_2)
```

**Points**
`ggplots` renders perfectly, and so does the animation `ggplotly(pl)`.

```
pl = ggplot() + 
   geom_point(data = df_1, aes(x, y, frame = frame)) 

# OK!
print(pl)
plotly::ggplotly(pl)
```

**Histogram**

`ggplots` renders perfectly.

```
gg_pl = ggplot() +
   geom_histogram(data = df_2, aes(
       val, 
       fill = factor(code), 
       frame = frame)) +
    scale_fill_brewer()

# OK
print(gg_pl)
```

but the rendering via `ggplotly` crashes

```
# Error!
plotly::ggplotly(gg_pl)
```

> Error in -data$group : invalid argument to unary operator

**Histogram + Points**

As before, `ggplot` works but the animation does not.

```
pl = ggplot() + 
   geom_point(data = df_1, aes(x, y, frame = frame)) + 
   geom_histogram(data = df_2, 
        aes(val, fill = factor(code), frame = frame))

# OK!
print(pl)

# Errors as before
plotly::ggplotly(pl)
```

Comment: Is there a typo in your `df_2` definition? It won't run for me as is.

Comment: @Jon Oh yes I am sorry an extra bracket -- I fixed it now.

Comment: Hi @qubert, I have this issue as well.  Did you ever manage to figure out a fix?

Comment: Not really, sorry... if you find one I'd be happy to know as well! Thanks

Comment: I have a solution using plotly, which I will post.  It does not have smooth transitions unfortunately.

Comment: It also doesn't animate the point at the same time as the histogram. @qubert

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite what you are looking for, but it's a start, and maybe it helps. Here's an animated histogram using plot_ly.

```
library(plotly)
p = df_2 %>% 
  plot_ly(x=~val, 
          type='histogram', 
          color=~code,
          frame=~frame, 
          alpha=0.7)
p
```

I couldn't get the dots to animate with the histogram, but here is the same thing with dots on top. If you uncomment the `#frame=~frame` line, the dots will animate, but the histogram will disappear except for the first and last frame.

```
  p = plot_ly() %>%
  add_histogram(data=df_2, 
                x=~val, 
                color=~code, 
                frame=~frame)%>%
  add_trace(data=df_1, 
            x=~x, 
            y=~y, 
            frame=~frame, 
            type='scatter', 
            mode='markers')
p %>% animation_opts(easing='linear')
```